# HTML redirect within body tags?

Tags: html, ios, redirect, uiwebview

Is there a method that gives the same result as the meta redirect that can be used in the body of an html doc? Or a reference in the body to CSS? I've been searching but the only things I can find want to make use of other technologies.

N.B. this is for an iOS UIWebView so no php and I'd rather not load any extra js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use Javascript, something like this should help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
</script>
```

Check this link to see how to place that inside a function that can be called with **"onclick"** or **"on body load"**, etc...

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

---

**EDITED:**

Another good thing to read about this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location

Answer (score 5):

I would use both meta and js redirects, also you may be interested on SEO by using *rel="canonical"*:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://stackoverflow.com/"/>        
    <script type="text/javascript">            
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); 
    </script>
    <title>Redirection</title>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://stackoverflow.com/">
    </noscript>
    If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>link </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than needing an onload event, this works without user interaction

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      let url = "https://www.w3docs.com";
      window.location.href = url;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```